# Grabbing data from multiple child components Vue js

Tags: vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I'm breaking my head for a few days now, trying to figure out how to grab the data from child components.

Situation is like this.

I have one parent component called `Post` where user can select date, title, description and which can contain multiple instances of `Event` compontents.
`Event` component contains fields like title, description, attendees.

User should be able to add multiple `Event`components which means I have multiple components `Event` within the `Post` component.

So, I can't figure out how can I compose my components to have an array of `Event` objects inside my `Post` component which I can later on send to my API.

the structure of the `post` object I need is:

```js
// Post.vue
{ 
    "date": '',
    "name": '',
    "description": '',
    "events": {
       {
        "title": '',
        "description": '',
        "attendees": ''
       },
       {
        "title": '',
        "description": '',
        "attendees": ''
       }
    }
}
```

So, I don't know should and how I would use vuex for it. I've tried using $emit to pass the data but I couldn't find it fit to get the data into `Post` model.

Can someone point me where should I look for it?

**EDIT #1**: Added sample code

The code for the components:

```js
<template>
  <v-form>
    <v-container>
      <v-row>
        <v-col
          cols="12"
          md="4"
        >
          <v-date-picker v-model="post.date" scrollable>
            <v-spacer />
            <v-btn text color="primary" @click="modal = false">
              Cancel
            </v-btn>
            <v-btn text color="primary" @click="$refs.dialog.save(date)">
              OK
            </v-btn>
          </v-date-picker>
        </v-col>

        <v-col
          cols="12"
          md="4"
        >
          <v-text-field
            v-model="post.name"
            label="name"
            required
          />
        </v-col>

        <v-col
          cols="12"
          md="4"
        >
          <v-textarea
            v-model="post.description"
            name="description"
            label="Description"
            dense
            value
            rows="4"
            hint
          />
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
      <v-row>
        <v-btn primary rounded @click="addLine">
          Add Event
        </v-btn>
        <v-expansion-panels accordion>
          <UserEvent
            v-for="(line, index) in lines"
            :key="index"
            @addLine="addLine"
            @removeLine="removeLine(index)"
          />
        </v-expansion-panels>
      </v-row>
    </v-container>
  </v-form>
</template>

<script>
import UserEvent from './partials/event'
export default {
  name: 'Post',
  components: { UserEvent },
  data () {
    return {
      post: [],
      lines: [],
      blockRemoval: true
    }
  },
  watch: {
    lines () {
      this.blockRemoval = this.lines.length <= 1
    }
  },
  mounted () {
  },
  methods: {
    addLine () {
      const checkEmptyLines = this.lines.filter(line => line.number === null)
      if (checkEmptyLines.length >= 1 && this.lines.length > 0) { return }
      this.lines.push({
        title: null,
        description: null,
        attendees: null
      })
    },
    removeLine (lineId) {
      if (!this.blockRemoval) { this.lines.splice(lineId, 1) }
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

And the child component UserEvent

```js
// UserEvent.vue
<template>
  <v-expansion-panel>
    <v-expansion-panel-header>Event details</v-expansion-panel-header>
    <v-expansion-panel-content>
      <v-row>
        <v-col cols="12" md="6">
          <v-text-field
            v-model="event.title"
            label="Title"
            required
          />
        </v-col>

        <v-col
          cols="12"
          md="6"
        >
          <v-text-field
            v-model="event.atttendees"
            label="Atendees"
            required
          />
        </v-col>

        <v-col
          cols="12"
          md="12"
        >
          <v-textarea
            v-model="event.description"
            name="description"
            label="Description"
            dense
            value
            rows="4"
            hint
          />
        </v-col>
        <v-col
          cols="12"
          md="3"
        >
          <div class="block float-right">
            <v-btn @click="removeLine(index)" />
            <v-btn v-if="index + 1 === lines.length" @click="addLine" />
          </div>
        </v-col>
      </v-row>
    </v-expansion-panel-content>
  </v-expansion-panel>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'UserEvent',
  props: ['line', 'index'],
  data () {
    return {
      event: []
    }
  },
  methods: {
    addLine () {
      this.$emit('addLine')
    },
    removeLine (index) {
      this.$emit('removeLine', index)
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Comment: The child elements could `$emit` each time they have new data. The parent could collect that data and `post` as needed to a backend. This is about as specific as I can be without a code sample.

Comment: Hi David, I've updated the question with the sample code. What I'd like to know is: Is it possible to keep the `UserEvents` in sync with the parent component, or I can update the parent component only by using `this.$emit` events?

Comment: The parent component Post should be the only one responsible for holding the state. The children should use v-model to transmit the user input to Post. Take a look at : https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components  
(you should think about the Event component as a custom input)

Comment: I thought of that as well. I'm just confused about how to make sure that the proper event is updated or removed from the `Post` store.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example with a similar structure what was posed in the question:

```
{
  name: String,
  events: [
    title: String,
    description: String,
  ],
}
```

This example allows the user to open a form to add a new event. When that form is submitted, the event data is added to the parent component's state.

**Parent**

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <input v-model="name" />
    <ul v-if="events.length">
      <li v-for="(event, index) in events" :key="index">
        <span>{{ event.title }}</span>
        <span>{{ event.description }}</span>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <Event v-if="isNewEventFormVisible" @submit="addEvent" />
    <button v-else @click="showNewEventForm">add event</button>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
import Event from '~/components/Event';

export default {
  components: { Event },
  data() {
    return {
      name: 'Example Post',
      events: [],
      isNewEventFormVisible: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    addEvent({ title, description }) {
      this.isNewEventFormVisible = false;
      this.events.push({ title, description });
      // TODO: call you API here to update
    },
    showNewEventForm() {
      this.isNewEventFormVisible = true;
    },
  },
};
```

**Event**

```html
<template>
  <form @submit.prevent="onSubmit">
    <input v-model.trim="title" type="text" />
    <br />
    <textarea v-model.trim="description" />
    <button type="submit">submit</button>
  </form>
</template>
```

```js
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      title: '',
      description: '',
    };
  },
  methods: {
    onSubmit() {
      this.$emit('submit', {
        title: this.title,
        description: this.description,
      });
    },
  },
};
```

You could imagine a more sophisticated version of this where events are editable. In that case, each `Event` could take props and bind them as values to its input instead of using `v-model`s.